# RecyclerView.Adapter onClick ClassCastException

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to load a `Fragment` inside an `Activity` and I was able to load the items. Now, what I want to do is to click the items on the list and pass it to the `DetailsView.class` which is a `Fragment` that will receive the bundle data. But everytime I click on the item I always get an error. Below is the logcat error that I'm getting

**Logcat Error**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.example.LoadAFragment cannot be cast to com.test.example.MainActivity at com.test.example.controller.DetailsView.onCreateView(DetailsView.java:178)
```

line java:178

```
MainActivity activity = ((MainActivity) getActivity());
```

**LoadAFragment.class**

```
public class LoadAFragment extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.load_layout);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_container, myFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

**RecyclerView Adapter**

```
public class MyFragmentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<ListModel> list;
    private Context mContext = null;
    private DetailsView detailsView;

    public MyFragmentAdapter(Context context, List<ListModel> list) {
        mContext = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final ListModel list = list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        String mID = list.getID();
        final int id = Integer.valueOf(mID );
        ((MyViewHolder) holder).title.setText(list.getTitle());
        ((MyViewHolder) holder).caption.setText(list.getCaption());
        ((MyViewHolder) holder).itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager manager = ((Activity) mContext).getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("id", id);
                detailsView = new DetailsView ();
                detailsView.setTitle(title);
                detailsView.setArguments(bundle);
                transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, detailsView);
                transaction.addToBackStack("list");
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (list != null? list.size():0);
    }

    private class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView title;
        public TextView caption;

        MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            caption = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.caption );
        }
    }
}
```

**MyFragment.class**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

    List<ListModel> list;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    MyFragmentAdapter myFragmentAdapter;
    ListDb listDb;

    public MyFragment() {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

        listDb = new ListDb(getActivity());
        list = listDb.getList();
        myFragmentAdapter = new MyFragmentAdapter (getActivity(), list);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myFragmentAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**DetailsView.class**

```
public class DetailsView extends Fragment{
     private MainActivity activity;
Bundle b;

public DetailsView() {}

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null)
            b = savedInstanceState.getBundle("save");
      }

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        activity = ((MainActivity) getActivity());
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);}
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (b != null) {
            setTitle(b.getString("title"));
            id = b.getInt("id");
        }
        if (b != this.getArguments().getInt("id")) {
            b = this.getArguments().getInt("id");
            //get data from id
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post your detail view class code

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 I've updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best and cleanest solution would be to pass a listener to the adapter.

```
public interface MyClickListener {
    void onResult(Data data);
}


public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, MyClickListener listener, List<ListModel> list) {
        mContext = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Data data = getData(position);
        //bind views

        holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.onResult(data);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Have the Fragment implement the listener and create the new adapter.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements MyClickListener  {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(),this,listData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(Data data) {

        //do work after an item is clicked
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast getActivity() to 'LoadAFragment' instead of 'MainActivity' in DetailsView.java. This way:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    activity = ((LoadAFragment) getActivity());
    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way to get Reference of `MainActivity` in your `DetailViewFragment`

```
private MainActivity parent_activity;

 @Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity)
{
    parent_activity = (MainActivity.class.isAssignableFrom(activity
            .getClass())) ? (MainActivity) activity : null;
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onDetach()
{
    parent_activity = null;
    super.onDetach();
}
```

Now use the reference using:

```
 if(parent_activity!=null)
{
   parent_activity.someMethod();
}
```